# how to begin{tabu}[t]?

Tags: tabu

I want to put my figures and plots at the top of the page. This with figure works

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{results}}
%  \vspace{2.0cm}
  \centerline{(a) Result 1}\medskip
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{results}}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
  \centerline{(b) Results 3}\medskip
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{results}}
%  \vspace{1.5cm}
  \centerline{(c) Result 4}\medskip
\end{minipage}
%
\caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results.}
\label{fig:res}
%
\end{figure}
```

but the code below doesnt work.

```
\begin{tabu}[t] to 0.8\columnwidth { | X[c] | X[c] | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Methods} & \textbf{Time in seconds} \\
    \hline
    MCG-D & 160  \\
    \hline
    MCG  & 100  \\
    \hline  
    SS  & 15 \\
    \hline  
    EB & 1.5  \\
    \hline  
    3DOP &  1.2 \\
    \hline  
    BING &  \textbf{0.01} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Ours} & 0.12 \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent environment of `figure` for tables is the `table` environment. Wrap your `tabu` in a `table` environment:

```
\begin{table}[t]
  \begin{tabu} to 0.8\columnwidth { | X[c] | X[c] | }
  ...
  \end{tabu}
  \caption{Some caption.}
\end{table}
```